# How to make node.js server accessible by public ip-address

Tags: node.js

I've been trying to make an online multiplayer game using nodeJS and socket.io. I am able to access through localhost:3000 to test out my website, but then now I want my friends to access it too.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server, {});
server.listen(3000);
```

How can I make it so that other people can access my website using my public IP address that I found on http://cmyip.com, for example [external-ip]:3000.

I tried using ngrok, but it's very slow and socket.io that emits data every 30 ms is exceeding ngrok limit. Also, I don't want to use any DNS or other plugins, I just want it to be simple.

I'm using Mac OS so my firewall is disabled by default.

Here is my port-forwarding page: (my Local IP is 192.168.1.50)
Am I doing it right? I have tried port-forwarding with games, and it works fine so I don't think it's my router.
[image]

Answer (score 11):

If you sure that you don't have problem with router then you can try to listen `0.0.0.0` this mean you will listen external and internal IP adresses.

`server.listen(3000,"0.0.0.0");`

Also you still need to check your Brandmauer or Firewall.